# Cloud Run 503 error due to high cpu usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I just implemented cloud run to process/encode video for my mobile application. I have recently gotten an unknown 503 error: `POST 503 Google-Cloud-Tasks: The request failed because the HTTP connection to the instance had an error.`

My process starts when a user uploads a video to cloud storage, then a function is triggered and sends the video source path to cloud tasks to be enqueued for encoding. Finally cloud run downloads the video, processes it via ffmpeg, and uploads everything to a separate bucket (all downloaded temp files are deleted).

I know video encoding is a cpu heavy task, but my application only allows up to ~3 minute videos to be encoded (usually around 100 MB). It works perfectly fine for shorter videos, but ones on the longer end flag the `503` error after processing for 2+ minutes

My instances are only used for video encoding and only allow 1 concurrent request/instance. Here are my services settings:

- **CPU** - 2 cpu
- **Memory** - 2 Gb
- **Concurrency** - 1
- **Request Timeout** - 900 seconds (15 minutes)

The documentation states that it is because of heavy cpu tasks so it's clear it is caused by the processing of heavier files, but I'm unsure what I can do to fix this given the max settings. Is it possible to set a cap on the CPU so it doesn't go overboard? Or is cloud run not a good solution for this kind of task?

Comment: Do you have logs for Cloud Task? How log take your request?

Comment: Where in the docs does it say "it is because of heavy cpu task" the containers will crash? I'm suspecting something else is at play here. Please check your application logs on Cloud Run.

Comment: I'd check the Cloud Run logs to find any hints at why the HTTP connection to the instance had an error. This will most likely give you an answer, which you can then act on it accordingly. Then, depending on the answer (could be various reasons), I'd look into your Cloud Run memory and/or your concurrency settings.

Comment: It mentions high cpu usage and this error here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#concurrency

Comment: The only logs that occur are the ones detailing the process started and is working, but after around ~2 minutes on a longer video, it logs the 503 error with no other information

Comment: _HTTP response code 503_ means that your service was unavailable at the time of the request. If you see [503 errors under high load](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#concurrency), it probably means that you may need to gradually increase your concurrency settings until you find an acceptable value. Each request your service handles requires some amount of additional memory. So, when you adjust concurrency up or down, make sure you adjust your memory limit as well. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#using_concurrency) for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Run crashes after 121 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092543/cloud-run-crashes-after-121-seconds)