# Cloud Run crashes after 121 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I'm triggering a long running scraping Cloud Run function with a PubSub topic and subscription trigger. Everytime I run it it does crash after 121.8 seconds but I don't get why.

```
POST 503 556B 121.8s APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html) https://????.a.run.app/

The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.
```

I've got a built-in timeout trigger and when I set it at 1 minute the functions runs without any problems but when I set at 2 minutes the above error gets triggered so it must be something with the Cloud Run or Subscription timeout settings but I've tried to increase those (read more below).

**Things involved**

1 x Cloud Run
1 x SubPub subscription
1 x SubPub topic

**These are the things I've checked**

- The timeout of the Cloud Run instance (900 sec)
- The timeout of the Pubsub subscription (Acknowledgement deadline - 600 sec & Message retention duration - 10 minutes)
- I've increased the memory to 4GB and that is way above what it's needed.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please try to share an example of code that reproduces the issue

Comment: @Steren It's hell of a long code and different files so it's going to be a hassle.
But I'm 99% sure I've isolated the problem to a timeout (If the function runs above 121.8s it return 503) so I'm pretty sure it's all about settings in GCP.

Why I'm sure about this is because if I run the function with an internal timeout trigger for 1 minutes it always runs and return with an 200 status code.

Comment: Is the log that you share a Cloud Run log? In addition, you perform scrapping, I guess you perform a lot of outgoing calls, right? If so, can you identify which URL that you reach cause this error?

Comment: Do you have any logs that explicitly return a timeout error? The reason I ask is because you mentioned that everything works with a shorter timeout limit, which is an odd behaviour so it might be something else that is causing it.

Comment: This is the log ```2020-09-29 08:24:45.492 CESTPOST503556 B121.7 sAPIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html) https://.....app/
The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.```

Comment: It's not the same URL that causes the problem. It differ between different URLs based on how fast the scraper scraped the URLs as well as how many concurrent scraper instance there were - The only thing that is the "same" for all the error is that it ends after 121.7s to 121.9s.

Comment: There's a very high chance something is wrong with your application. Have you tried this locally? Please try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Yes, locally I have no problem to scrape the whole array in one sweep without any error.
I had it running for 5 minutes. Are you sure there are no more timeout limits that can be edited more than the ones I added in my first post?

Comment: Should not be a memory problem either since the Container memory utilisation hits a miximum of 16% memory usage

Comment: Now I tried to lower the scrape limit to only 3 urls and then after the scraping was done I added a timeout that were 150s long to isolate if it's the scraper that is the problem but still it gives a 503 error after 120s so it's not something with the scraper that causes the problem.

Comment: @JohiOakey honestly at this point it will be pretty difficult to pinpoint the cause of the issue without inspecting your project and that is something that can only be done by google cloud's paid support, here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/support) where you can find more information about it. Also you could try to open a bug report in Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0) to check if this is a not a bug in Cloud Run Itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: See the answer below. And note that [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) say: *In addition to changing the Cloud Run request timeout, you should also check your language framework to see whether it has its own request timeout setting that you must also update.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to Node.js' default server timeout of 120secs.

Try `server.setTimeout(0)` to remove this timeout.

Comment: That's most likely it indeed. The Cloud Run [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) already mention: *"In addition to changing the Cloud Run request timeout, you should also check your language framework to see whether it has its own request timeout setting that you must also update."*