# Impact of The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have 2 nodeJs services running in cloud run, `application_A` and `application_B`, using pub-sub service as a mode of communication.
`application_A` sends data to `application_B`, and upon receiving the data `application_B` process the data and publishes it back.
At some instance I receive the error `The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.` in `application_B`.
I would like to know the impact of this error on the on-going tasks running in `application_B`.
Does the application restarts?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, each Cloud Run instance can receive concurrent requests. Meaning, several requests can share the instance before Cloud Run spins up a new one depending on the demand and how you configured the service. You can see more details by reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency_values).

To answer your question, if your service is configured to accept concurrent requests, then a request can fail but the instance will still continue handling new requests or on-going tasks without restarting. However, if your application exits (for instance due to an error in your application code) or if the instance crashes down because it ran out of memory, then it is terminated.

Once all the requests are finished and there are no more incoming requests, the instance will become [idle](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#idle-instance) for a while, then proceeds at scaling down. The cycle repeats and Cloud Run starts up new instances once there's new incoming requests.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Really helpful 
I have one more doubt. does cloud run produces same response for both out of memory and concurrency issue? If so, how can we identify the cause of the issue?

Comment: The error will be clear at the logs because the instance will be terminated. Concurrency when mishandled can cause exceeding the limit. It is possible that your failing requests hits a [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396388/7031308). However, if you believe that it's a memory issue, I suggest looking at memory utilization in the console UI, and consider [optimizing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits#optimizing) the memory of your instance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It does not seem like error message in the logs is giving much information about the cause. ```The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.``` This is what I get in logs.

Comment: I have just gone through the memory utilization, it seemed to be below 60%. However there is a sudden dip from 60% to 10% when the error occurred.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. First, check how long the requests would take before they fail, then check how much memory each request have used. Finally, I suggest posting a new question, because the original question is about the impact of the error, not troubleshooting it.

Comment: I updated my answer. This blog will help you understand: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Really helpful to understand how cloud run actually works. I will go ahead and post a new question for troubleshooting.